# Laravel base_path() gives error - Call to undefined method baseDir()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a tester class and I'm trying to use the global helper method `base_path()`, but I get the error below:

```
Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Container\Container::basePath()
/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:182
/myproject/tests/Feature/DataCsvSeedTest.php:31
/myproject/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:195
/myproject/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:148
```

Looks like helper.php in Laravel calls basePath(), and can't find it. Am I missing a namespace or some other setting for the global helper functions? Using Laravel 5.5.

```
<?php    
namespace Tests\Feature;
use Tests\TestCase;

class DataCsvSeedTest extends TestCase
{
   public function setUp()
   {
    $baseDir = base_path();
    print "basedir = ". $baseDir;
   }
}
```

Comment: `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: `composer dump_autoload` did not work.

Comment: please check the answer

Answer (score 11):

Ah... This is a testClass,

```
class DataCsvSeedTest extends TestCase
{
   public function setUp()
   {
     parent::setUp();

     $baseDir = base_path();
     print "basedir = ". $baseDir;
   }
}
```

when you are overriding `setUp()` method don't forget to call the `parent::Setup()`, which will bootstrap the application.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: @Les Mark it as the answer, please.