# Unable to whitelist files due to the use of base_path() in Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit, code-coverage

I am trying to generate a code coverage report using PHPUnit. When I whitelist all the app directories for code coverage reports, the following error will be produced.

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Container\Container::basePath()`

The base_path() function has been used in helpers and the number of controllers and each of them is producing the above error. I was able to produce a code coverage report of a file which do not use the base_path() method.

I am using PHP 7.4, Laravel 5.7, PHPUnit 7.5.30, Xdebug 3.0.3

Comment: Does this SO post help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48415390/laravel-base-path-gives-error-call-to-undefined-method-basedir/48415438

Comment: No, It did not work as it was not similar to my problem.